# GET Request from API via Python export to csv

Tags: python, json, csv, request, token

I'm trying to write a api script via python. I want to access the URL "https://xxx/2.0/article" via "requests.get" so that it is displayed. If this was successful, I want to reprogram it to write all "articles" into a CSV.

I worked with curl first and it worked well

```
curl -X GET \
https://xxx/2.0/contact \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {access-token}'
```

It also displayed the data directly. When I tried this with Python, it gave me an "Unauthorized".

```
 import requests
 newHeaders = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
 response = requests.get('https://api.bexio.com/2.0/article', headers={'Authorization': 'newHeaders' 
 'Bearer '})
 print(response.status_code)
 print(response.text)
```

I don't know exactly what I have to do to make this work and how I can export/write this directly to a CSV.

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why to use different authorization header?

Comment: It was a fault from my side. I change it and now to output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with the auth

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests

url = "https://api.bexio.com/2.0/article"

headers = {
'Accept': "application/json",
'Content-Type': "application/json",
'Authorization': "Bearer }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I saw my fault. The last question is, how can i get the output in a csv file? When I make an export of my stock in the frontend, I get a CSV with the fields "Product" "Code" "Storage location" Purchase value" "Stock" and "Minimum stock". But with the script comes of course much more output.